# How to solve 100% disk usage?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

I have 100% disk usage, I tried many ways and disabled some services but the problem remains the same, also I tried to boot with safe mode and I opened resource monitor and watched the curve for Disk(I/O) going up to max and down (with out using any app). Any suggestion or description to my problem ?

Comment: What does resource monitor tell you?  That is, what processes are running that result in high disk usage.  Windows 10 here:  Run a Full Scan with Windows Defender to look for viruses.

Comment: Registry, System.. I tried full scan with windows defender but there is no viruses and everything was clear with this scan.

Comment: There must be some program then using the disk all the time. Look in Task Manager, Details tab and see if a service with a name or other identifier shows up.

Comment: One approach neither satisfying is to (1) start removing software until you get the offender or (2) back up, install Windows fresh and build up slowly until something offends. The second approach is best if you are up to it.

Comment: Resource Monitor tells you the program. Look at it more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You could try these steps:

1. Temporarily Disable Windows Search

   - Open CMD in admin mode
   - Run `net.exe stop "Windows search"`
   - Check if the disk usage have improved if so you should disable Windows search for good. You do that by opening Windows services -> locate "Windows Search" service - Right click it and go into properties -> On "Genereal" tab change "Startup type" option to disabled.
2. Update your device drivers - amanualy or with help from some tool, I like DriverEasy and IOBIT Driver Booster
3. Disable SuperFetch(SuperFetch helps to decrease boot time and make must-load programs more efficiently.)

   - Open CMD as admin
   - Run `net.exe stop superfetch`
   - Wait for few minutes then check your computers disk usage
4. Perform a disk check

   - Open CMD as admin
   - Run `chkdsk.exe /f /r`
   - Disk check will start the next time you boot your PC and it might take some time to complete. After Restart check your diks usage
5. Reset Virtual memory

   - Open "Advanced system settings" (press Windows key and Pause/ Break key at the same time. Then choose Advanced System Settings on the left panel.)
   - Switch to the "Advanced" tab and under 'Performance"  section click on "Settings"
   - On Performance otpions form, switch to the "Advanced" tab again and under "Virtual memory" section click on "Change" button
   - Uncheck the "Automatically manage paging file size for all drives" option
   - Select "Custom size"
   - For the "Initial size" type the amount of RAM you have and for the "Maximum size" type the 1.5*(the amount of RAM you have installed)
   - Click "Set"
   - Clear all of your TEMP files. press Windows key and R at the same time, then in the Run form, type temp and hit Enter. This will invoke Windows Explorer with your Temp folder open, showing you all the temp files on your computer. Delete them all.
6. Disable Antivirus software temporarily
7. Change your Google Chrome & Skype settings
8. for more visit [8 fixes for 100% disk usage on Windows 10](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/100-disk-usage-windows-10-fixed/)

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the Windows auto-update mechanism uses lots of disk bandwidth in the background while it's working on installing the next update. Check in the settings/resource monitor to see if this is the case.

Comment: Check how, exactly?